# What AWS S3 class is used by RDS backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

According to [AWS RDS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/?nc1=h_ls), "Amazon RDS DB snapshots and automated backups are stored in S3."

I wonder what [S3 class](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) is used by AWS ?

I want to know if RDS backups are stored only on the same availability zone or is there a copy on an other availability zone ?

Comment: I don't know for sure and can't find a reference right now, but my experience with AWS makes me suspect S3 standard. AWS would _not_ store this data in one AZ, it makes no sense, and for RDS restores they'll want the data to be available quickly for restores. They charge $0.09 per GB for RDS backups which is four times higher than then cost of S3 standard, which hints towards the S3 class.

Comment: You might be right and I hope you are right. I whish I can find a reference to confirm.